# dispatch_once singleton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

I need to convert the following Objective-C code to Swift.

```
static RWBasicCell *sizingCell = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
  sizingCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
});
```

How do I do that? I Googled and found out this example.

```
class SingletonC {

    class var sharedInstance : SingletonC {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance : SingletonC? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SingletonC()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

But is it for returning a single of a class.

Comment: The other questions on this topic have had to do with shared singleton instances of a class, whereas this is about a static variable within the scope of a function. Initialization is different in this case from an always-available singleton, so a different question seems useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout), right? Swift doesn't have static variables that can be scoped to functions, but you *can* nest a type inside a function, and give it static variable. Here's a Swift equivalent version of the start of that method:

```
func heightForBasicCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    struct Static {
        static var sizingCell: RWBasicCell?
    }

    if Static.sizingCell == nil {
        Static.sizingCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(RWBasicCellIdentifier) as RWBasicCell
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes! I'm doing that tutorial in Swift. Thank you. It works :)